# How to loop through each textfields in javafx?

Tags: loops, javafx, textfield

I have a program which have 40 textfields. I want to know how to loop on each and setText. Each textFields have already different fxid's. Help please! I  want to code it concisely.

Comment: One option would be using this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34470630/2991525

Answer (score 2):

You would need a `List` to keep track of each `TextField`.  Your question does not include any code so it's difficult to determine the easiest way to do this in your situation, but there are a couple of options.

1. **Same layout container:** If all the `TextField` controls are contained within the same layout container, such as a `VBox` or `FlowPane`, you could use the list of children for that container: `vbox.getChildren()`
2. **Create your own `List`:** If you have the `fx:id` for all your `TextFields`, then add them to a `List`: list.add(textField)

Now that you have the list, just iterate over them either using an iterator or a simple `for` loop:

**Container Children:**

```
for (Node node : root.getChildren()) {
    // If you're certain all the children ARE TextFields, cast the node now
    ((TextField) node).setText("Yay for text!");
}
```

**Your Own List:**

```
    // Create a List to track all the TextFields
    List<TextField> textFieldList = new ArrayList<>();

    // Add some TextFields to the list
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        textFieldList.add(new TextField());
    }

    // Now iterate over the list of TextFields and set their text
    for (TextField textField :
            textFieldList) {
        textField.setText("Yay for text again!");
    }
```

Comment: Sure thing! If this answers your initially question, please click the check mark to accept it and post the next question as a new one. Glad to help!

Comment: The "Your Own List" code executes for me, but it does not appear to have any affect on / interaction with the TextFields in my javafx program. What should I do?