# How the access the multiple fx:id efficiently (in FXML Document Controller)?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I have to set values for labels, I am set values by following way which is very lengthy,

```
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    private TilesLogic gl = new TilesLogic();
    private List<List<Integer>> game;

    @FXML
    private Label C1;
    @FXML
    private Label C2;
    @FXML
    private Label C3;
    @FXML
    .
    .
    .
    private Label C16;
    @FXML
    private Label timer;


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        game = gl.shuffle();
        SetValues();
    }    

    void SetValues(){
       C1.setText(String.valueOf(game.get(0).get(0)));
       C2.setText(String.valueOf(game.get(0).get(1)));
       .
       .
       C15.setText(String.valueOf(game.get(3).get(2)));
       C16.setText(String.valueOf(game.get(3).get(3)));
    }
}
```

is that any other way just like that

```
    for(int i =1;i<17;i++)
           setText("#C"+String.valueOf(i),String.valueOf(game.get(i))); 
           // setText("#id","Sometext");
```

to do it simple way and less time ?

Comment: no that's not possible - but you are not _forced_ to use fxml :) simply don't if pure code is easier to setup. unrelated: java naming conventions please!

Comment: You could structure your view in such a way that a `Parent` nodes holds all of the `Labels` only.  Then you can do something like `parent.getChildren().foreach(node-> ((Label)node).setText("..."));`

Comment: You can put the elements into a list via fxml file, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/34470630/2991525 However ask yourself, if creating&adding these labels could be done inside the `initialize` method using a loop; if this is possible with a reasonable amount of code, it's usually preferable to creating multiple elements via fxml with similar structure (Don't repeat yourself!).