# JavaFX initialize array of TextFields

Tags: java, arrays, javafx, initialization

I am trying to create array of TextFields in JavaFX but getting error. 
I have 10 TextFields: path1, path2... path10.

```
//initialization
@FXML
private TextField path1,path2,path3,path4,path5,path6,path7,path8,path9,path10;
@FXML
private TextField[] paths = {path1,path2,path3,path4,path5,path6,path7,path8,path9,path10};
```

However, when I write

```
String text = paths[0].getText();
paths[1].setText(name);
```

This first line gets me NullPointerException.

The solution I found is to use Initizlizatior of my Сontroller, but this is so ugly:

```
public void initialize(URL fxmlFileColation, ResourceBundle resources) {
    paths[0] = path1;
    paths[1] = path2;
    paths[2] = path3;
    paths[3] = path4;
    paths[4] = path5;
    paths[5] = path6;
    paths[6] = path7;
    paths[7] = path8;
    paths[8] = path9;
    paths[9] = path10;
}
```

How can I get rid of manual assinment in many lines and make

```
@FXML
 private TextField[] paths = {path1,path2,path3,path4,path5,path6,path7,path8,path9,path10};
```

work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [create array of Label using FXML in JavaFX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28587297/create-array-of-label-using-fxml-in-javafx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot make this exact code work. The array creation in

```
private TextField[] paths = {path1,path2,path3,path4,path5,path6,path7,path8,path9,path10};
```

happens in the initializer. The loading process for fxml files works like this however:

1. Create controller class instance (or use a existing one).
2. Load fxml content injecting objects created by the loader.
3. Call `initialize` on the controller, if it exists.

The above code is executed in step 1 while the objects you want to store in the array are created later in step 2.

You can work around this by using the fxml to create a `List` of the `TextField`s and inject it to the controller ([see my answer to *Grouping together JavaFX FXML Objects*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34470630/2991525))

Of course you can also create a array of `TextField`s containing specific elements using a array initializer in the `initialize` method:

```
public void initialize() {
    paths = new TextField[] {path1,path2,path3,path4,path5,path6,path7,path8,path9,path10};
}
```

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer! However I cannot understand first part of your answer. Just made it work  in Void Initialise(). Could you please suggest reading to understand this?

Comment: @Vittori0: I described the approach in the answer I linked. It just inserts the `Node`s to the scene graph and a list. See [*Introduction to FXML*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html), sections "Define Blocks"/fx:reference. If you were refering to the description of the loading process, read the Controllers section on that page;fields that are initialized during the creation of the object, which happens before the `FXMLLoader` uses the controller instance later by injecting the fields and this is when the `path` fields become non-`null`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can. You need to declare the variables separately so FXML can initialise the variable. Then, you would need to make your `TextField` array work by setting each element to something. The best way of doing it would be to use the solution you have in the `initialize(...)` function and use it for what it meant to do – initialising things.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution i use

```
 TextField[] txt = new TextField[beanFields.length];
 for (int i=0; i<=beanFields.length-1; i++) {
                TextField textField = new TextField();
                txt[i] = textField;
                textField.setPrefWidth(200);
                textField.setPrefHeight(32);
    }
```

Comment: What is beanFields here?