# Using JavaFX scene builder to fill fx id with buttons in an array

Tags: javafx

I need 15 buttons in my application but I dont want to declare them one by one like

```
@FXML
private Button button1;
@FXML
private Button button2;
@FXML
private Button button3;
...
...
...
...
```

Instead, I want to this, create a array of buttons.

```
@FXML
private Button[][] button = new Button[5][3];
```

However, In the scene builder, there is only one button that I can choose and I think it reference to the array not the single button element.
Is there any way that I can easily make this work?

Answer (score 3):

Note that is possible to store the data in a `ArrayList` as GoXR3Plus described in his answer. However you cannot create an array in fxml. To do this you'd need create the array from java code (e.g. in the `initialize` method) and attach some information to the `Node` that allows you to retrieve the index information.

This could e.g. be done by using a static helper method to attach information as well as a css class selector to the nodes, and inject a common ancestor of these nodes to the controller:

```xml
<VBox fx:id="root" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="fxml.arraystore.StoreController">
    <children>
        <Button text="1" Helper.indices="0 0"/>
        <Button text="2" Helper.indices="0 1"/>
        <Button text="3" Helper.indices="1 1"/>
        <Button text="4" Helper.indices="1 0"/>
        <Button text="5" Helper.indices="2 0"/>
        <Button text="6" Helper.indices="2 1"/>
    </children>
</VBox>
```

**Helper**

```
public class Helper {

    private static final String MARK_CLASS = "array-store-mark";
    private static final String MARK_CLASS_SELECTOR = "." + MARK_CLASS;
    private static final String INDICES_KEY = "arrayStoreIndices";

    public static void setIndices(Node node, String indices) {
        if (node == null || indices == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        String[] parts = indices.split("\\s+");
        int[] is = new int[]{Integer.parseInt(parts[0]), Integer.parseInt(parts[1])};

        // add css class
        node.getStyleClass().add(MARK_CLASS);

        // add index data
        node.getProperties().put(INDICES_KEY, is);
    }

    public static <T extends Node> T[][] getAsArray(Node parent, Class<T> nodeClass) {
        if (parent == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        int max1 = 0;
        int max2 = 0;

        // find nodes by class
        Set<Node> marked = parent.lookupAll(MARK_CLASS_SELECTOR);

        // find array size
        for (Node n : marked) {
            n.getStyleClass().remove(MARK_CLASS);
            if (nodeClass.isAssignableFrom(n.getClass())) {
                int[] is = (int[]) n.getProperties().get(INDICES_KEY);
                if (max1 < is[0]) {
                    max1 = is[0];
                }
                if (max2 < is[1]) {
                    max2 = is[1];
                }
            }
        }

        T[][] result = (T[][]) Array.newInstance(nodeClass, max1+1, max2+1);

        // put data in array
        for (Node n : marked) {
            int[] is = (int[]) n.getProperties().remove(INDICES_KEY);

            if (nodeClass.isAssignableFrom(n.getClass())) {
                result[is[0]][is[1]] = (T) n;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

}
```

**Controller class**

```
public class StoreController {

    // common parent
    @FXML
    private Parent root;

    private Button[][] buttons;

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        buttons = Helper.getAsArray(root, Button.class);
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(buttons));
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It is like a next level solution that I probably didn't get it. I will study your code so hard!

Answer (score 1):

*I assume that you can only modify it by playing with the code of the `fxml` file.*

For a simple `ArrayList` you can do the below(check [fx:define](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#define_elements) and [fx:reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#reference_elements)):

**First way->1**

```
        <fx:define>
          <!-- create buttons and store them in a list -->
           <ArrayList fx:id="buttonsArray">
              <Button fx:id="firstButton" />
              <Button fx:id="secondButton" />
              <Button fx:id="thirdButton" />
           </ArrayList>
        </fx:define>


        <!-- add buttons in the list to scene graph -->
        <fx:reference source="firstButton"/>
        <fx:reference source="secondButton"/>
        <fx:reference source="thirdButton"/>
```

**Second way->2**

```
        <!-- add buttons in the list to scene graph -->
         <Button fx:id="firstButton" />
         <Button fx:id="secondButton" />
         <Button fx:id="thirdButton" />

       <fx:define>
          <!--store them into a list -->
           <ArrayList fx:id="buttonsArray">
               <fx:reference source="firstButton"/>
               <fx:reference source="secondButton"/>
               <fx:reference source="thirdButton"/>
           </ArrayList>
        </fx:define>
```

---

About a multi dimensional **ArrayList[ 3 ][ 2 ] Using the first way->1** it must be something like:

```
       <fx:define>
          <!-- create buttons and store them in a list -->
           <ArrayList fx:id="array">
              <Button fx:id="Button_0_0" /> //first row , first column
              <Button fx:id="Button_0_1" />
              <Button fx:id="Button_0_2" />
              <ArrayList fx:id="buttonsArray">
                  <Button fx:id="Button_1_0" /> //second row , first column
                  <Button fx:id="Button_1_1" />
                  <Button fx:id="Button_1_2" />
              </ArrayList>
           </ArrayList>
        </fx:define>


         <!-- add buttons in the list to scene graph -->
         <fx:reference source="Button_0_0" />
         <fx:reference source="Button_0_1" />
         <fx:reference source="Button_0_2" />
         <fx:reference source="Button_1_0" />
         <fx:reference source="Button_1_1" />
         <fx:reference source="Button_1_2" />
```

---

I reccomend you read all the links given above and also:

1)[create array of Label using FXML in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28587297/create-array-of-label-using-fxml-in-javafx)

2)[Grouping together JavaFX FXML Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34469447/grouping-together-javafx-fxml-objects)

Comment: Thank you so much !  I totally understand it